# How can we visualize the lag between voltage and current in capacitor or inductor? i.e. When voltage goes down Current goes up...

Tags: capacitor, inductor

Its hard to imagine the scenario and contradicts basic understanding.

Comment: YOu know that if you apply a sine voltage across parallel LC , current is also sine wave in both. When you understand which part reaches peak current either at 0V or max rate of change, you can relate this to leading current or lagging current  after this point.  If not go back to static DC characteristics and dv/dt and di/dt

Comment: LTspice. Free download.

Comment: Also, there is really no "lag" or "lead". I don't like that concept, it's a simplification to teach AC electricity to technicians fifty years ago. You can't break causality.

Comment: IF you can imagine a sine wave V vs I trace in XY mode.  Which one rotates CW and which CCW ? (depends on xy) No matter, but they do go in opposite directions.

Comment: I am fairly sure this question, or one very similar, has already been answered.

Comment: To get the phase relationships the correct way around remember ELI the ICE man  ( E - voltage, L - inductance , I -current and C - capacitor .)  **Voltage leads current** in an inductor and **current leads voltage** in a capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

if you live near a place where you can watch the tides flow between a narrow sea path to fill and empty a (parltly) enclosed path you can see it happening: the strongest flow occurs halfway between high and low, at the high and low momenst the flow is almost zero.

A bit less pronounced is the temperature cycle. The hottest part of the day (measured by the air temperature, not by the temperature of a sun-exposed surface) is not a 12:00 when the heat from the sun is at its maximum, but somewhat later, when the influx of heat is lower, but more heat has accumulated.

The key point in both cases (and in the AC current + capacitor case) is storage: the maximum amount stored (heat, water, charge, ...) occurs after the maximum influx, because it is the sum of all previous influx, hence as long as the influx is positive the amount stored still rises. The maximum occurs when the influx reaches zero, after that the amount stored lowers because the influx is negative (call it an out-flux if you want).

Answer (score 0):

The idea of "lag" or "lead" is a little confusing but can be helpful if you understand he context. Consider a system where we only have resistors, capacitors and inductors. Voltage and Current sources are the same frequency and phase locked, meaning they may have different phase relationships but these are not time dependent.

In such a system we can see for a capacitor

$$I = C\cdot \frac{dV}{dt}$$

And if we take \$V\$ to be a pure sine wave then current is a cosine so appears to lead by \$90^o\$

In the case of an Inductor

$$V = L \cdot \frac{dI}{dt}$$

So current lags voltage, or voltage lags current.

Both of these are meaningless concepts except in the case where circuits are driven by sine waves and have had enough time to settle to a stable state.

The concept however is useful mathematically to help us understand several ac circuits such as filters.